# SQL breaking up an int and multiplying each digit

Tags: sql

If I have the following as an int 1234 and have broken it up into 1,2,3,4 how could I make it so that they will be separated and be able to multiply them for example 1 × 3, 2× 5, 3×3, 4×5 having the pattern of 3,5 not taking into account if they are even or odd.

Comment: What do you mean by "not taking in count if they are even or odd" ? Because it really seems to be what you are doing: 1 is in position 0 (even) -> multiply by 3, 2 is position 2 (odd) -> multiply by 5, etc...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, your question doesn't make sense.  Where does "5" come from?

Comment: Alternate multiplication of digits in an 'int' by 3 & 5 using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is sql-server version but should work in several others.  Idea is you take a Tally table, a table of sequential numbers, then join it to the number of the digits of the integer, then do your calculations/cutting up of things.

http://rextester.com/JTUXP51597

```
;WITH cteBase AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
)

, cteTally AS (
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as N
    FROM
       cteBase c10
       CROSS JOIN cteBase c100
)

, cteValue AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1234)) t(value)
)

SELECT
    v.value
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(v.value AS VARCHAR(100)), t.N, 1) AS INT) as Digit
    ,CASE t.N % 2 WHEN 0 THEN 5 ELSE 3 END as Multiplier
    ,SUBSTRING(CAST(v.value AS VARCHAR(100)), t.N, 1) + ' x ' + CASE t.N % 2 WHEN 0 THEN '5' ELSE '3' END as Equation
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(v.value AS VARCHAR(100)), t.N, 1) AS INT) * CASE t.N % 2 WHEN 0 THEN 5 ELSE 3 END as Result
FROM
    cteValue v
    INNER JOIN cteTally t
    ON LEN(CAST(v.value AS VARCHAR(100))) >= t.N
```